# How to know which customers bought me regularly month to month in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question. I have the next dataframe. The example is just a resume of all the info I have.

| Name | Product | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Product1 | December | 2020 |
| Name2 | Product2 | December | 2020 |
| Name3 | Product2 | December | 2020 |
| Name1 | Product1 | January | 2021 |
| Name2 | Product2 | January | 2021 |
| Name3 | Product2 | January | 2021 |
| Name1 | Product1 | February | 2021 |
| Name2 | Product2 | March | 2021 |
| Name3 | Product2 | February | 2021 |
| Name1 | Product1 | March | 2021 |
| Name3 | Product2 | March | 2021 |
| Name1 | Product1 | April | 2021 |
| Name3 | Product2 | April | 2021 |
| Name1 | Product1 | Jun | 2021 |
| Name3 | Product1 | Jun | 2021 |
| Name1 | Product1 | July | 2021 |
| Name3 | Product2 | July | 2021 |
| Name1 | Product1 | August | 2021 |
| Name2 | Product2 | August | 2021 |
| Name3 | Product2 | August | 2021 |

So I want to know how to get my clients that have been with me regularly, like

| Name | Product | Months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Product1 | 9 |
| Name3 | Product2 | 9 |

As you can see, my name2 was excluded because it was not part of the clients that bought me regularly, like Jan-Feb-Mar-Apr-......,etc. Is any way to do this using python?. My dataframe have data from many years.

Comment: do you define regular as someone who has an entry in every month?

Comment: Yes, that have bought me every month.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `groupby` and `count` like such. If you want to say anyone with only 1 month out of the year is not consistent then filter by months in that year, you could change this variable filter:

Input:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','Product', 'Year'])['Month'].count().reset_index()

df[df['Month'] > 11]
```

Example Output:

```
    Name    Product     Year    Month
1   Name1   Product1    2021    7
3   Name2   Product2    2021    3
6   Name3   Product2    2021    6
```

Comment: I don't think you are considering the consistency of the buyer. For example, Name1: have bought in January-March-April-August I want that clients that have never stop buying month to month, in you´re code Name2 doesn´t have to be there.

Comment: is the expectation that regular means - 12 months out of the year or, no skips in months, or what is the benchmark for regular? since that can be arbittary?

Comment: No, by regular, I mean the customer appears every single month of the year. Like you, James, you have bought all the 12 months so you will appear on the results. The point of this exercise is to analyze which customers deserve a reward because they have been buying for consecutive months.

Comment: Okay. I’ve updated the solution to filter by those who are only with you for 12 months. That is per your example